# Running external Python script from Pyinstaller

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller, popen

I write an application using Pyinstaller which installs Python on the target machine and some packages. At the end of the application I am supposed to spawn a Python script and I use `subprocess.Popen()`. However, it appears that script cannot execute it as it appears to still use the application's (pyinstaller's) runtime environment. However, running the resulting script stand alone after the installation works.

Is there a way to spawn a process outside the pyinstaller's context?

Comment: This [article](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-subprocess) might shed some light on the situation. Most likely, you are not using `Popen` "correctly" - as in the way pyinstaller can handle it in your OS.

Comment: As to modifying the env pyinstaller apps run in, there is a mention in the docs here: http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html?highlight=popen#ld-library-path-libpath-considerations

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing some approaches I made for this problem (at least for my use case).

The first approach would be in the resulting script that is spawned during installation, I explicitly remove the first entry in the `PYTHONPATH` if it is empty (i.e. the current directory). This ensures that the necessary Python libraries that are outside the current context (the PyInstaller bootloader) are loaded  first. i.e.

```
if not sys.path[0]:
    sys.path.pop(0)
```

For the second approach, there are instances that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable refers to the directory of the extracted installer. Usually occurring in Linux, I would send a modified environment variable set to the `subprocess.Popen()` where `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is removed.

```
pip_env = os.environ
if 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' in pip_env:
    pip_env.pop('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
subprocess.call("<command here>", shell=True, env=pip_env)
```

Beware of using the above approaches, though. Although it worked on my use case, it may cause unexpected issues for other use cases.